# Como substituir um parâmetro de uma função PHP por um arquivo que vai receber de um formulário?

Tags: php, html

É o seguinte pessoal, tenho esse formulário que envia um arquivo para o servidor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Enviando arquivos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- O tipo de encoding de dados, enctype, DEVE ser especificado abaixo      -->
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">

        <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE deve preceder o campo input -->
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4194304" />

        <!-- O Nome do elemento input determina o nome da array $_FILES -->
        Enviar esse arquivo: <input name="arquivoEnviado" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar arquivo" />

    </form>

    <br />



</body>
```

E esse que faz o upload do arquivo:

```
 <?php

/* Insira aqui a pasta que deseja salvar o arquivo */
$uploaddir = './uploads/';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo Enviado <br />" . $_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['name'] . "<br />" .
    $_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['size'] . $_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['type'];
} else {
    if ($_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE) {

        echo "Tamanho excedido.";
    };
}
?>
```

E esse que cria o arquivo zip:

```
/* Inicando o objeto ZipArchive */
$zip = new ZipArchive();

/* O primeiro parâmetro indica o arquivo que será aberto, logo após a 
 * constante ZipArchive::CREATE é utilizada para criar o arquivo 'arquivo.zip'
 * caso ele não exista. */
if ($zip->open('arquivo.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {

    /* O método addFile() recebe dois parâmetros, o nome e o nome de destino. */
    $zip->addFile('adwcleaner_6.020.exe', 'ADWCleaner.exe');

    /* O método addFile() recebe dois parâmetros, o nome e local do arquivo e o nome de destino. */
    $zip->addFile('GBPCEF.exe', 'extensao/SoftCaixaEconomica');

    /* O método addFromString() cria um arquivo que contenha Strings, no segundo parâmetro recebe 
     * o conteúdo do arquivo de texto. */
    $zip->addFromString('detalhes.txt', "Programa pre remover adwares");

    $zip->close();

    echo "Arquivo criado com sucesso.";
}
```

Como eu faço pra alterar o argumento da função addFile() por uma variável ou arquivo que venha do formulário? Terei que criar outro formulário e no action chamar outro código .php?

Comment: Coloque um campo texto no formulário e resgate o valor `$_POST`!

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua colocação @VirgilioNovic

Comment: No formulario crie um campo `<input type="text" name="nome"/> ` e resgate no `PHP` com `$_POST['nome'];`, entendeu.

Comment: Mas eu não quero criar outro campo, eu só quero que saber como pegar um arquivo do formulario e adicionar no argumento da função addFile. Entendeu?

Comment: Eu fiz um exemplo simples e funcional

Answer (score 1):

***Assim:***

Primeiro você precisa pegar a informação que vem do formulário e passar para um diretório com a função [**move_upload_file**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['tmp_name'],
                   'tmp/'.$_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['name']);
```

nesse caso eu coloquei em um pasta dentro do projeto **`tmp/`**. Depois de ter colocado em um diretório utilize o arquivo gravado como primeiro paramento do método `addFile` como sugerido abaixo:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open('tmp/arquivo.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) 
{
    $zip->addFile('tmp/'.$_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['name'],
                  $_FILES['arquivoEnviado']['name']);
    $zip->close();
    echo "Arquivo criado com sucesso";
}
```